# How to update UI based on FileUpload control change

Tags: asp.net

I have an FileUpload control on a page.  I need to change some values based on the filename once a user selects a file.  I'm trying to find out the best way to do this.  The only option I can see is listening in JavaScript for a change event and then either..

a) forcing a post back and updating the form

b) updating things on the client side using JavaScript and some back end async calls.

Is there any other options and if not which of this is preferable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery, you can attach a function to the `change` of the file upload.

Consider the following example html:

```
<input id="myFile" type="file">
<p><label id="myLabel">No File</label></p>
```

And let's say we wanted to update the `label` with the name of the selected file. To do that, we'd use the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myFile").change(function () {
        $("#myLabel").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ffkuL/1/

If you *aren't* using jquery, you can do something like this:

```
var upload = document.getElementById("myFile");

upload.onchange = function (e) {   
    var label = document.getElementById("myLabel");
    label.innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

And here's a fiddle for that one: http://jsfiddle.net/8PYwK/

(Honestly, though, I find that it's far simpler in the long run to use jquery in the long run when dealing with ASP.NET controls.)

Obviously, the label changing in my samples are just examples. Following that pattern, though, you can make whatever changes you need to on the client side (rather than needing to post back).